# Post value prevent sql injection

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to ask if I can prevent sql injection with this code?

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "lists");  
    if (isset($_POST['main'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $main = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["main"]);
    $sub = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["sub"]);

    query . . . .

    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Use prepared statements and parameterized queries.
You can do it like this:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name=? and age=?');
$stmt->bind_param('si', $_POST['name'], $_POST['age']);
$stmt->execute();
```

The 'si' means string and integer, each letter to every param corresponding to every '?'.
Further info can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

Regards.

Comment: But how in two post values?

Comment: @user3097736 updated answer, give it a look at my link first example. $code goes to first ?, $language goes to second ?...